# How to download an image in android using emulator

Tags: android

I have the code to download an image from network. There are no errors.But when I open the application, it gets crashed. I thought it because of the internet connection. So i gave the path, where the image is stored in my system.But still its crashing. Any solution for this?

Here's the code

```
*MainActivity.java*

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        public static final String URL ="Users/sangetha/Documents/news_icon_1.png";
        ImageView imageView;
        Button button;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_view_from_url);
            //Get the id of button & Image
            imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.icon);
            button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_click);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     // Create an object for subclass of AsyncTask
                    DownloadImageTask task=new DownloadImageTask();
                      // Execute the task
                       task.execute(new String[] { URL });
                }
            });

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
            }
        }
```

I have called as sync task outside the on create method

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{
    @Override
          protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls){
            Bitmap map = null;
            for (String url : urls) {
            map = downloadImage(url);
         }
        return map; 
        }
    // Sets the Bitmap returned by doInBackground
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
    // Creates Bitmap from InputStream and returns it
    private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

        try {
            stream = getHttpConnection(url);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.
                    decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
    // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
    private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.connect();

            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.image_view_from_url, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_image_view_from_url, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}}
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
    android:maxHeight="70dp"
    android:maxWidth="70dp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_click"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="@string/button_click"/>
```

What's the problem?Can anyone please help me

Comment: Can you update your logcat error.

Comment: 04-02 03:18:26.059: W/dalvikvm(1923): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a2bba8)
04-02 03:18:26.079: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 03:18:26.079: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): Process: com.example.assignment2, PID: 1923
04-02 03:18:26.079: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.assignment2/com.example.assignment2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

04-02 03:18:26.079: E/AndroidRuntime(1923):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)

Comment: I'm getting null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

Your image view is called imageView not icon:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"...
```

Try the following:
`imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);`

The NullPointerException occurs because you are casting a null, as a result of `findViewById(R.id.icon)`, to an ImageView.